# Replace image url from API when it's null

Tags: reactjs, api

How can I replace the `image.url` to a placeholder like this https://via.placeholder.com/300?  when there exists no image for that specific item because I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null

I use strapi API and have checked that everything else works – so if I reupload that image for the specific item everything works, but i'd like a better error handling

I've tried the code below but it changes nothing so if there's anyone who is able to help, thanks!

```
{items.map(function(item){
 const {id, name, image} = item;
  return <MyCard key={id} id={id} 
         name={name} 
         image={image.url || 'https://via.placeholder.com/300'} 

})}
```

code for the MyCard component:

```
function  MyCard({id, name, image}){
    return(
        <>
            <Card>
                <Card.Header>
                    <Card.Img src={image} alt={name}/>
                </Card.Header>

                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{name}</Card.Title>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
image={image.url || 'https://via.placeholder.com/300'}
```

To

```
image={image?.url || 'https://via.placeholder.com/300'}
```

Image is null so you can't access url

Answer (score 1):

change

```js
image={image.url || 'https://via.placeholder.com/300'}
```

to

```js
image={image?.url ?? 'https://via.placeholder.com/300'}
```